# verificar iterativamente se os elementos de um dicionário possuem a mesma chave e realizar operações com os valores do dicionário

Tags: python, numpy

Tenho um dicionário de `arrays`, preciso percorrer todos os arrays do dicionário e verificar de forma iterativa se os `arrays` estão contidos na mesma chave.

Caso se trate de arrays em uma mesma chave do dicionário, eu preencho a posição referente de sua matriz de custo com o custo zero.

Caso se trate de arrays em chaves distintas, preciso calcular a distância euclidiana entre esses arrays e armazenar o valor calculado na respectiva posição i j da matriz de custo.

Exemplo dicionário:

```
{0: array([[21.8472593 , 23.07639831]]), 1: array([[8.54825372, 1.23984289],
   [8.30116683, 1.73755953],[7.89875198, 2.12075148],
   [7.38954636, 2.34320015],
   [6.83496766, 2.37807495],
   [6.30190627, 2.22116945],
   [5.85465726, 1.89140877],
   [5.54716545, 1.42856693],
   [5.41651891, 0.88846947],
   [5.47847552, 0.33626013]]), 2: array([[ 4.3455991 , 17.14658312],
   [ 3.88626636, 17.45929259],
   [ 3.34768183, 17.59604232],
   [ 2.79480676, 17.54033827],
   [ 2.29432605, 17.29889918],
   [ 1.90660505, 16.90084616],
   [ 1.67840863, 16.39419028],
   [ 1.63726066, 15.84004172],
   [ 1.78812419, 15.30523897],
   [ 2.11280285, 14.85428714]])}
```

Com o código abaixo eu consigo iterar da forma que quero para preencher a matriz, porém eu preciso que o tamanho da minha matriz seja i x j, onde i = j = instance.values(). Mas estou obtendo uma matriz com i^2 x j^2!!!!.
Como resolvo a dimensionalidade da matriz?

---

```
for k,  v in instance.items():
    for q, w in instance.items():
    #guardo os arrays de cada chave em matrizes auxiliares que eu possa iterar
        aux_v = v
        aux_w = w
        for i in range(len(v)):
            for j in range(len(w)):
                if k == q:
                    costMatrix[i][j]=0
                  
                else:
                    dist = np.linalg.norm(aux_v[i] - aux_w[j])
                    costMatrix[i][j]= dist  * 1e3 + M
```

'''

Comment: Não deu pra entender como estão os arrays (já que `1: array1, array2, array3` é uma sintaxe inválida). Se vc faz `print(instance)`, o que aparece?

Comment: Por exemplo: 0: [0,0] , 1: [0,1], [2,2], [3,2], 2: [3,2], [4,4], [5,1], esse seria um dicionário com 3 chaves (grupos) de arrays (pontos).

Comment: Eu sugiro [edit] a pergunta e colocar essa informação lá (é melhor porque dá pra formatar, ficando mais fácil visualizar)

Comment: ok, vou fazer isto. Obrigada.

Comment: A sintaxe continua errada, um dicionário de listas de listas seria provavelmente assim: `{0: [[0,0]] , 1: [[0,1], [2,2], [3,2]] 2: [[3,2], [4,4], [5,1]]}`

Comment: É um dicionário de arrays, e não de listas. Este é exatamente o dicionário que eu quero percorrer, preciso construiur a matriz de custos com as dimensões do dicionário nas linhas e nas colunas.

Comment: hkotsubo muito obrigada pela edição, ficou perfeita!!!

Comment: Mas tu disse que tem mais de um array na mesma chave, então ou é um dicionário de arrays de arrays, ou um dicionário de listas de arrays

Comment: A sintaxe é um print do que o meu programa me dá, um dicionário de arrays, onde tenho arrays com apenas uma linha e duas colunas, e outros com 10 linhas e duas colunas. Conforme o problema que preciso resolver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atualização: esclarecido nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553893/verificar-iterativamente-se-os-elementos-de-um-dicion%c3%a1rio-possuem-a-mesma-chave/553908#comment986432_553908) e na pergunta qual é o objetivo do algoritmo, existe um método do numpy para iterar sobre arrays de dimensão desconhecida que é o [nditer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html).

Assumindo que cada valor do teu dicionário pode ser tratado como um array único, então:

```py
import numpy as np

instance = {0: array([[21.8472593 , 23.07639831]]), 1: array([[8.54825372, 1.23984289],
   [8.30116683, 1.73755953],[7.89875198, 2.12075148],
   [7.38954636, 2.34320015],
   [6.83496766, 2.37807495],
   [6.30190627, 2.22116945],
   [5.85465726, 1.89140877],
   [5.54716545, 1.42856693],
   [5.41651891, 0.88846947],
   [5.47847552, 0.33626013]]), 2: array([[ 4.3455991 , 17.14658312],
   [ 3.88626636, 17.45929259],
   [ 3.34768183, 17.59604232],
   [ 2.79480676, 17.54033827],
   [ 2.29432605, 17.29889918],
   [ 1.90660505, 16.90084616],
   [ 1.67840863, 16.39419028],
   [ 1.63726066, 15.84004172],
   [ 1.78812419, 15.30523897],
   [ 2.11280285, 14.85428714]])}
M = 0.0
costMatrix = dict()
for chave_um, valor_um in instance.items():
    for chave_dois, valor_dois in instance.items():
        for indice_um, array_um in enumerate(np.nditer(valor_um)):
            costMatrix[indice_um] = dict()
            for indice_dois, array_dois in enumerate(np.nditer(valor_dois)):
                ed = np.linalg.norm(valor_um - valor_dois)
                costMatrix[indice_um][indice_dois] = ed * 1e3 + M
print(costMatrix)
```

Não é necessário testar se o array está na mesma posição, porque a distância euclidiana entre um ponto e ele mesmo é 0.0. Mas se isto for um requisito,então o array é o mesmo somente se `(chave_um == chave_dois) and (indice_um = indice_dois)`.

---

Em relação ao cálculo de distância euclidiana, o norm() do módulo de álgebra linear do numpy só funciona porque a ordem padrão é equivalente a calcular a distância euclidiana, mas esse método vai retornar um array do numpy, e não a distância. No scipy tem uma função que faz exatamente o que tu quer:

```py
import scipy
ed = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(array1, array2)
```

---

Resposta anterior para referência:

Iterar sobre `range(len(dicionario.values()))` é anti pytônico. Existem métodos para iterar em dicionários mais eficazes, dependendo do que tu precisa fazer.

Depender do método `sorted()` pra ordenar dicionários não é confiável. Dicionários em Python não são ordenados. Para os casos onde tu precisa de ordem existe o [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), mas neste caso ele não é necessário.

Dito isto, tem como fazer seguindo a lógica que tu apresentou. O que tu quer é iterar sobre as chaves, e não sobre os valores. Usar uma sequência de números presumindo que o dicionário está bem formado e respeitando essa sequência é possível mas quase sempre desnecessário, e este caso não é exceção. Tu pode iterar sobre as chaves com o iterador `instance.keys()`:

```py
for i in instance.keys():
    for j in instance.keys():
        if i == j:
            costMatrix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            ed = np.linalg.norm(instance[i] - instance[j])
            costMatrix[i][j] = ed * 1e3 + M
```

É muito mais fácil acessar os valores do dicionário se tu tem a chave, do que acessar a chave a partir do valor.

Se precisar dos valores tu pode obter as chaves e valores com o iterador `instance.items()`:

```py
for chave_um, valor_um in instance.items():
    for chave_dois, valor_dois in instance.items():
        if chave_um == chave_dois:
            costMatrix[chave_um][chave_dois] = 0
        else:
            ed = np.linalg.norm(valor_um - valor_dois)
            costMatrix[chave_um][chave_dois] = ed * 1e3 + M
```

Mas como eu escrevi, essa abordagem é ineficiente. Ela é útil pra enxergar melhor o que está acontecendo. Já que tu está usando numpy, tem métodos mais eficientes, rápidos de fazer a mesma coisa. Estudar estes métodos e aprimorar o código é um exercício para quem está lendo. Até simples compreensões de lista e dicionários já melhorariam a eficiência neste caso.

Comment: Sim eu consegui iterar, mas tenho um novo problema. Meu dicionário como disse é formado por arrays, quando os array pertencem a chaves diferentes eu preciso acessar cada array individual dentro de cada chave e calcular uma distância euclidiana entre eles.

Comment: Essa dúvida não estava contida na pergunta, sugiro que tu edite a pergunta e inclua a descrição do algoritmo para que fique mais claro

Comment: Ou então cria uma nova pergunta, já que ela tem outro escopo e diverge dessa pergunta aqui.

Comment: Obrigada, eu editei a pergunta, por favor veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: O teu código ficou mais complicado do que a pergunta original, na resposta que eu tinha dado antes já estava otimizado mesmo pra fazer o que tu quer agora. A resposta continua válida. Acrescentei uma alternativa para cálculo de distância euclidiana.

Comment: Oi Iuri, mas usando a sua resposta eu não consigo calcular a distancia entre cada um dos arrays dentro de cada chave. Meu dicionário contém vários arrays em cada chave e cada array é um ponto, e eu preciso calcular a distância entre todos os pontos que estão em chaves distintas. A dimensão da matriz que vou construir não é [chave1][chave2] mas sim [len(instancia.values()][len(instancia.values(]

Comment: Só falta uma informação pra eu entender aonde tu quer chegar: tu quer calcular a distância entre um par de coordenadas para todos os outros pares de coordenadas exceto aqueles que estiverem na mesma chave do dicionário?

Comment: `len(instancia.values())`, `len(instancia.keys())`,`len(instancia.items())` e `len(instancia)` devem ser o mesmo número

Comment: Isso! Quero calcular a distância entre todos os pares de coordenadas, guardar isso numa matriz. Exceto para as coordenadas que estão na mesma chave do dicionário. Para estes a distância deve ser 0.

Comment: Bom, então eu tenho outra dúvida. Não está mais claro qual é o tamanho de cada uma das duas dimensões da matriz. Pelo jeito o tamanho da primeira dimensão é igual ao número total de arrays de todas as chaves do dicionário original, e o tamanho de cada dimensão é este mesmo número menos a quantidade de arrays da mesma chave do array correspondente à atual primeira dimensão.

Comment: Eu preciso preencher todas as dimensões da matriz, só que na posição i,j para arrays da mesma chave devo preencher com zero. Eu preciso dessa informação, não posso deixar sem preencher. Eu preciso de uma matriz que tenha as duas dimensões com o tamanho total do número de arrays que tenho no dicionário.

Comment: Então cada posição da segunda dimensão tem que ser um array de arrays, exceto uma e o tamanho da matriz então na verdade é `matriz[len(instancia)][len(instancia[n])]`

Comment: Resposta atualizada conforme o esclarecimento no último comentário

Comment: Obrigada Iuri, funcionou direitinho assim!